# On Square.Retrofit, how setup the CallAdapter.Factory so that Retrofit use my CallAdapter<T, Foo<Bar<T>>>

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

My final goal here is to have the following retrofit interface declared:

```
interface SomeService {
  @GET("/path")
  fun getSomethingFlow() : Flow<DataState<SomeApiDataClass>>
}

data class DataState<T>(val data : T, state: State)
// the real data class is a big bigger, but that's the idea
// state is an enum
```

The intention is that my CallAdapter will handle the `Flow` and the `DataState` and let Moshi handle the `T`.

I've been following mostly from here https://github.com/MohammadSianaki/Retrofit2-Flow-Call-Adapter/tree/master/FlowAdapter/src/main/java/me/sianaki/flowretrofitadapter

So I created a `CallAdapter<T, Flow<DataState<T>>>` with `override fun adapt(call: Call<T>): Flow<DataState<T>>` that does all the processing I want it to do.

I've created the `CallAdapter.Factory()` and all the API data classes have Moshi annotation `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)`.

here is the CallAdapter.Factory:

```
    override fun get(
        returnType: Type,
        annotations: Array<out Annotation>,
        retrofit: Retrofit
    ): CallAdapter<*, *>? {
        if (getRawType(returnType) != Flow::class.java) {
            return null
        }
        if (returnType !is ParameterizedType) {
            return null
        }
        val flowType = getParameterUpperBound(0, returnType)
        val rawFlowType = getRawType(flowType)
        if (rawFlowType != DataState::class.java) {
            return null
        }

        return MyCallAdapter(flowType)
    }
```

and relevant CallAdapter code:

```
    override fun adapt(call: Call<T>): Flow<DataState<T>> {
        Log.d("TEST", "adapt $call")
        // do all my logic here.

        This method is never called!!!

        return dataState
    }

    override fun responseType(): Type {
        Log.d("TEST", "Retrofit is asking us the type")
        return returnType
    }
```

At the end I got my Retrofit building like:

```
        val api = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(MyAdapterFactory())
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl("https://.... ")
            .build()
            .create(SomeService::class.java)
```

When I try to call the API I get the following crash:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for com.package.DataState<com.package.SomeServiceDataClass>
        for method SomeService.getSomethingFlow
        at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:54)
        at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createResponseConverter(HttpServiceMethod.java:126)
        at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(HttpServiceMethod.java:85)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:39)
.....
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot serialize Kotlin type com.package.DataState Reflective serialization of Kotlin classes without using kotlin-reflect has undefined and unexpected behavior. Please use KotlinJsonAdapterFactory from the moshi-kotlin artifact or use code gen from the moshi-kotlin-codegen artifact.
        at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.create(ClassJsonAdapter.java:97)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:145)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:105)
```

It seems that even thou I gave to Retrofit a CallAdapter from `Call<T>` to `Flow<DataState<T>>`, it still trying to use data converters (moshi) for parsing the `DataState`.

On debugging I found that the Factory passes all the checks and returns a new `MyCallAdapter` and that Retrofit calls my `MyCallAdapter.responseType()`. So it's mostly there.

The `fun adapt(call: Call<T>): Flow<DataState<T>>`  is never called!

**So the question is**:

How do I tell retrofit to only use Moshi for `T` and leave the `DataState` to me?

Answer (score 0):

After crying a bit and re-considering some life choices, I found the solution.

It is a good ol' case of "should have better read the docs".
Check it out!!

[image: Retrofit Docs]

> Returns the value type that this adapter uses when converting the HTTP
> response body to a Java object. For example, the response type for
> Call is Repo. This type is used to prepare the call passed to
> #adapt. Note: This is typically not the same type as the returnType provided to this call adapter's factory.

So after updating the `Factory` this following snippet, it all works.

```
    override fun get(
        returnType: Type,
        annotations: Array<out Annotation>,
        retrofit: Retrofit
    ): CallAdapter<*, *>? {
        val typeOfFlow = getInnerType(returnType, Flow::class.java) ?: return null
        val typeOfDataState = getInnerType(typeOfFlow, DataState::class.java)?: return null

        return MyAdapter(typeOfDataState)
    }


  private fun getInnerType(type: Type, klazz: Class<*>): Type? {
        if (type !is ParameterizedType) {
            return null
        }
        if (getRawType(type) != klazz) {
            return null
        }
        return getParameterUpperBound(0, type)
    }
```

Comment: Was this to convert a custom object to a kotlin flow?

Comment: @IglesiasLeonardo I did for a Flow, but also got some special classes that can give either the class I want or an Error class that is the one the backend sends for every error.